# How to launch iOS Native Facebook App from my app with a public profile URL?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing an iOS app that needs to open a Facebook user or page profile on the Facebook App (if installed) from my app. I have the public profile URL of the user or page, such as https://www.facebook.com/nirav.parmar.7169709. How can I use a custom URL scheme to launch the Facebook App and show the profile? If the Facebook App is not installed, I want to open the profile in Safari instead.

I already tried this way but it's not work for me:

- fb://profile/nirav.parmar.7169709 (Not work)
- fb://profile?username=nirav.parmar.7169709 (Not Work)
- fb://profile/100004929307564 (worked - but how to find user_id from this url "https://www.facebook.com/nirav.parmar.7169709")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `canOpenURL` to check if app can be opened.

```
let appURL = URL(string: "fb://profile/100004929307564")!
let browserURL = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/nirav.parmar.7169709")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(appURL)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.open(browserURL)
}
```